# how to make after user logged in the php website, they can view his personal data only

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on internal payslip portal using php, so my question is when user logged in this portal they have access to view any ones data, so i want to make restrictions to users when they login they only visible his personal data only,like  google drive please help me

Comment: check the logged in users id matches the userid of the page he is on. if it doesn't, redirect

Comment: i am asking like after user login he view his data like files,image,pdf files only not others, like after you login to your google drive you can get your data only not any others data, i am asking like that only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `user_id` field in your database and store all the `data` of a user in its corresponding field. Now whenever a user gives password/username, you could easily get the `user_id` from your database. Now fetch all the information which correspond to that particular `user_id`.

Try to implement the above by yourself.

Comment: Yes I created and stored the data, that all process is done my question is after login of user they view only them documents not other in my page after user login every data files will showing to everyone

Comment: @Chiru fetch only those data which correspond to a particular user id

Comment: How can i do it please mention it, i wank script session user data view on web page